# Laravel Route Model Binding - Resource Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to automatically inject the model instances directly into routes with implicit or explicit binding.

```
Route::get('api/users/{user}', function (App\User $user) {
    return $user->email;
});
```

My question is, if we have resource controller, how to implement model binding?

```
Route::resource(''api/users, 'UserController')
```

Thank you